# not getting output when scheduled a jcl program in crontab

Tags: linux, scheduling, cron

dear friends i have a jcl program that uses PCO program .I want to schedule it every minute using crontab .i have done the entry in cronntab like below
* * * * * path/job
but the crontab is not producing any output but when i am seeing /var/log/crontab it is showing that crond has executed the job every minute but i am not getting any output
Plz help how to schedule that job

**I have read in internet that it can be because of environment variables not set properly
plz tell if that can be the case**

Answer (score 1):

Where do you expect the output to show up ? [`crontab`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/crontab.html)

> If standard output and standard error
>   are not redirected by commands
>   executed from the crontab entry, any
>   generated output or errors shall be
>   mailed, via an implementation-defined
>   method, to the user.

So you should redirect the output

```
 * * * * * path/job > /path/to/file
```

Alternatively, check your mail (`mail`).

Comment: in jcl the output is directed in spool directory

Comment: @maverick Edit your question and post some code. Ideally, you should post the smallest possible example that exhibits the problem.

Comment: i have tested the crond it is running and executing other inbuilt command like echo and other commands but only these jobs related to my project are not getting executed